# Check order in which buttons are pressed - Android

Tags: java, android, button

I have four buttons in my application. Each button has an integer as its text. How would I check to see whether the buttons are pressed in ascending order of their integer value? I want it such that if a button is pressed out of order, there will be a notification of some kind that tells the user that they have chosen the wrong order.

Comment: Which code have you already tried?

Comment: I have thought about adding 24 if statements to check all of the possible orders that the numbers could be in, but that obviously is not the way to go.

Comment: Actually you don't need 24 if statements. Create a variable that stores the number of the last button clicked, when you got a new click, you compare the new with the last one, if it's ok(right order) then you update the value of last clicked otherwise you tell the user.

Comment: @issathink Thank you for your idea but I would want the lowest value of all four buttons to be pressed first, not just them being pressed from lower to higher.

Comment: It's [Simon](http://www.handheldmuseum.com/MB/Simon.htm)!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
// put your button text integers in ascending order in an array
int[] integersInAscendingOrder =  {buttonText1, buttonText2, buttonText3, buttonText4};

int i = 0;

// for each button's on click listener do something like the following:
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(button.getText().toString());
        checkOrder(value);
    }
});

// have a function check order pressed
private void checkOrder(int value) {
    // see if the button pressed is the right one
    if (value == integersInAscendingOrder[i]) {
        if (i == 3) {
            // insert code to run once all buttons pressed in right order
        } else {
            // insert code (if any) where less than all buttons pushed but in right order
            // increase i
            i++; 
        }
    } else {
        // button out of order
        Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong order", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But when does i change value?

Comment: Edit: realized that I forgot to add the i++

Comment: Glad to hear it works.